# Proper way to say "more and bigger"

Tags: adjectives, conjunctions, comparatives

I want to communicate (in written language) that "there are more pictures and bigger pictures if you click the link", without writing "pictures" twice and sounding silly.

Is the construction "more and bigger pictures" proper English? Or is "more, bigger pictures" better?

Comment: This is the Internet. Nobody will read your sentence whatever it says. Make the link be "More/enlarge" and move on.

Comment: I'd tend to use "larger" rather than "bigger".

Comment: "See the [full gallery](http://google.com) for hires images." Try to use the noun as your link; this isn't 1995.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about reworking it to say "more pictures, including larger sizes, if you click the link"?